# Apache Cassandra 3.11.5 Installation

Tags: java, cassandra

Environment: Windows 10, 64-bit

While Apache Cassandra 3.11.4 (SSTable format - big) works straightaway. Wanted to try Apache Cassandra 3.11.5 for hoping it would support the new SSTable format (bti), am getting the below error:

> ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter:1] 2019-11-10 17:36:57,054
>   LogReplicaSet.java:94 - Failed to create log replica
>   C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377\md_txn_flush_971e9f90-03b2-11ea-be78-2d33aa3628d5.log
>   org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Invalid
>   folder descriptor trying to create log replica
>   C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\data\data\system\local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377

Have tried running with Admin privileges and also clearing the folder but the problem persists. The folder does get created but still the error.

Any clues or correction in Setup?

Comment: Can you try changing your directories in your cassandra.yaml files to see if that works (pick a folder you know you have privileges on)?

Comment: Thanks Jim for the suggestion. Tried a different directory option as well as Run As (for cmd) Administrator to elevate the privileges but still get the same error.  The folder in question "local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377" does get created but my guess is its the next step the MemtableFlushWriter that is failing.

Comment: Just fyi for others, I hear a Jira has been opened for this. CASSANDRA-15426 (link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15426).